# Google+ People Search API returns no items

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-apis-explorer

Is google+ people search deprecated?

I'm using the Try this API from their page
https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/search

and keep getting no items for different queries

```
{
 "kind": "plus#peopleFeed",
 "etag": "\"ucaTEV-ZanNH5M3SCxYRM0QRw2Y/K-_p8YwZl_F9FBOVSt8JEHLSg9Y\"",
 "selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people?
     query=jane%20smith&key=[mykey]",
 "title": "Google+ People Search Results",
 "nextPageToken": "",
  "items": []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, this broke in the past day or two, after working for years.

Answer (score 1):

No its not, I have been using it for the past two weeks within a .Net code but since yesterday there has been some mishaps (as you have shown no items return in searches that normally would return items).
If this is not the first time you use the API then I would try to use another google account for authentication (if you are using Auth2 not an API key). it might be a quota limit.
If this is your first time testing the API, then Id wait, peoplesearch.execute works around once in 15 times now (returns results vs no items at all), with no specific error returned to understand the reason. so it might be a glitch. Will update the answer once I reach a more solid conclusion.

Comment: It's working fine now. Probably maintenance or a glitch as you said

Comment: It havent worked at my side yet. would you plz confirm if its working today?

Comment: It looks like it's down again. Not very reliable

Comment: Is this bug tracked by Google and can I follow it? Link?

Comment: google should be following up all posts tagged with google-apis-explorer, but I have moved on to another project so I am not following up